# Definite integral incorrectly giving a nonreal value

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

fixed in **10.1** (windows and Mac OS X)

---

In *Mathematica* 10.0, when I enter

```
N[Integrate[Sqrt[1+x^3],{x,-1,3}]]
```

I get a nonreal value (*i.e.*, the imaginary part is nonzero.) Why?

This arose when I was seeing if `Sqrt[1+x^3]` has an elementary antiderivative.  MMA gives a result in terms of an elliptic integral, and this has nonreal values for x > 2.

Comment: `NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, -1, 3}]`

Comment: @belisarius Yes, `NIntegrate` does the job here, but the fact remains that `Integrate` doesn't.

Comment: Interestingly, Integrate[Sqrt[1+u^2],{u,-1,x}] gives a real-valued function (for x>=-1).

Comment: Wait a minute - scratch that.  It gives real values only for nonnegative  x.  Even for  x = -1, it gives a nonreal value!

Answer (score 10):

It is a bug. [Rubi](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) package gets it right:

Mathematica:

```
 r = Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, -1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Rubi

```
 r2 = Int[Sqrt[1 + x^3], x];
 Limit[r2, x -> 3] - Limit[r2, x -> -1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 N[%]
 (*8.18272 + 1.11022*10^-16 I*)
 Chop[%]
 (*8.18272*)
```

Looking at Out[91] and Out[94], we see they are not the same. Mathematica is missing the ellipticK part.

Here is Maple' result, which agrees with Rubi's

```
 int( sqrt(1+x^3),x=-1..3);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interestingly, the derivative of Mma's antiderivative gives $\sqrt{1+x^3}$ almost everywhere.  However the antiderivative is discontinuous at $x=2$.  There are jumps in both the real and imaginary parts there, which would result in the wrong answer for any definite integral across $x=2$ using that antiderivative.

Comment: @MarkAdler True, but would you concur in calling the current output a bug?

Comment: Absolutely!  The discontinuity makes the antiderivative useless for calculating integrals.

Comment: +1 for introducing Rubi! I didn't know about such a package.

Answer (score 5):

The integral is path-dependent (in the complex plane).  Help it out by specifying a real way-point:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, -1, 0, 3}]
N[%]
(*
  (Sqrt[π] Gamma[1/3])/(6 Gamma[11/6]) + 
   3 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/3, 4/3, -27]

  8.18272
*)
```

Check:

```
NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, -1, 3}]
(*
  8.18272
*)
```

---

**Update**

After reading [Mark Adler's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/94/mark-adler) comment, I thought I'd try `2` for a way-point.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, -1, 2, 3}]
N[%]
(*
  12/5 + (1/5 + I/5) (-1)^(5/6) Sqrt[2] 3^(3/4)
     EllipticF[ArcSin[(-1)^(11/12) 3^(1/4)], (-1)^(1/3)] + 
   3 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/3, 4/3, -27] - 
   2 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/3, 4/3, -8]

8.18272 - 7.21645*10^-16 I
*)
```

It can be seen to be round-off error if we evaluate the result with arbitrary precision:

```
N[%%]
(*
  8.182716621611494 + 0.*10^-21 I
*)
```

Comment: Without the midway point, the imaginary part of the answer given is far from 0.

Comment: However Mathematica should not need help evaluating that integral, seeing as how Rubi and Maple have no problem with it.  This sort of thing is just downright embarrassing when I'm trying to tell people how awesome Mathematica is.

Comment: @MarkAdler Of course.

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn Yes, I know. That's rather obvious, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkAdler [This happens](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbugs%5D+Integrate) all the time. I wasn't suggesting that things are ok because there's an obscure way to get the right answer.

Comment: I understand.  I was venting at Wolfram, not you.  The fact that this happens all the time is my beef.

Answer (score 3):

fixed in **10.1** windows

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
N[Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, -1, 3}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Even with Rubi's help, the result returned by *Mathematica* is an ugly looking elliptic integral expression with complex parameter. (Actually, even Maple's result is far from optimal as well.) Using methods similar to what I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33500), here is a closed form for the OP's integral:

```
N[(12 Sqrt[7] + 3^(3/4) InverseJacobiCN[(8 Sqrt[3] - 19)/13, (2 + Sqrt[3])/4])/5, 20]
   8.1827166216114944451

NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, -1, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   8.1827166216114944466
```

Comment: Note: The result in V10.1 is now the first result in my answer.  I suppose one might still argue that answering an elliptic integral in terms of elliptic functions is more elegant.

Comment: Actually, it's an *inverse* elliptic function that's featured in my answer; since `InverseJacobiCN[x, m] == EllipticF[ArcCos[x], m]`, it would have been acceptable for *Mathematica* to return something in terms of `EllipticF[]` had the *parameter m been real and in the interval* $(0,1)$ instead of being complex… oh well.

Comment: In my loose way of thinking, the inverse of $f$ is still in terms of $f$.  (I was just comparing `InverseJacobiCN ` to `Hypergeometric2F1`, and not in any serious way.)